# Preg_split captured all result in array

Tags: php, regex, delimiter, preg-split

I have a problem with the function `preg_split` in php

My regexp is

```
#^(-?[0-9]+)(([+x])(-?[0-9]+))*$#
```

I want for example transform :

```
-5+69x45
```

in an array like this

```
{
[0] = -5
[1] = +
[2] = 69
[3] = x
[4] = 45
}
```

My regexp work and math with preg_match

But with preg split I don't have my array

I have a empty array without flag or

```
{
[0] = -5
[1] = x
[2] = 45
}
```

With the flag PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your misunderstood `preg_split`.

The pattern you define is used to split the string, but that means those parts of the string that where matched by your pattern are not included in the resulting array.

By using the flag `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` content of the capturing groups is added to the resulting array ([preg_spit doc](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)).

```
#^(-?[0-9]+)(([+x])(-?[0-9]+))*$#
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But you have a quantifier here around your two last groups, that means in $2 and $3 is only the last match stored and the first match of this group the "+69" is overwritten, so in your case you get

```
$1 = -5
$2 = x
$3 = 45
```

Comment: Yes but if I use a simple regex like  #[+x]# in preg_split I have good number but not the delimiter. I wan't the both.

Comment: @Jebik Then just put brackets around `#([+x])#` and use the flag `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` that those matches are added to the resulting array, this should give you then what you want.

Comment: Just one more thing i'm new and i don't know how to close a question.
How mark this question in resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
$str = '-5+69x45';
$arr = 
 preg_split('#([+x]|-?\d+)#', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => -5
    [1] => +
    [2] => 69
    [3] => x
    [4] => 45
)
```